# Is it possible to access specific formgroup value onsubmit

Tags: angular, submit, form-control, formgroups

Inside one component,

there are 2 form groups.

Both form has a submit type input and few form controls.

like below .
Form group A and B.

```
<form [formGroup]...>
  <input formControlName.../><button type="submit" .../>
</form>
<form [formGroup]...>
  <input formControlName.../><button type="submit" .../>
</form>
```

My question is, how can I access a particular form group value from these two form control, in 1 `onSubmit()` function ?

Comment: Your submit action triggers your submit function therefore you should be able to access whatever `FormGroup` object your desired form is bound to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use this syntax:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)">
</form>
```

Comment: Face palm, I think I forget that submit type need (ngSubmit) to direct it back to typescript. No wonder my onSubmit function has no response. Thanks alot.

Comment: It happens with all of us. You're welcome.

Comment: One thing tho, for my case, Somehow onSubmit should be empty (). Just a note if above solution brings some bug.